# Flutter Text Is Not Centered

Tags: flutter

**I have a code like this:**

```
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 25, 25, 25),
  body: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        const Text("Güvenli ve Gizli", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.02),
        AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: ezAnimation,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return Center(
              child: Image.asset("assets/SecureAndHiddenIcon.png", fit: BoxFit.cover, color: Colors.white, height: 200)
            );
          }
        ),
        SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.02),
        Center(child: Text("Kullanıcıya değer vermek, güvenlik ve gizliliği sağlamaktan başlar. Malum tarayıcılar gibi bilgilerinizi satmayız!", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white))), // !!!!!!!!!!!!! <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

"Kullanıcıya değer vermek, güvenlik ve gizliliği sağlamaktan başlar. Malum tarayıcılar gibi bilgilerinizi satmayız!" written `Text` is not centered even though it is inside the `Center` widget. Why does this problem occur? How to I solve it?

Comment: Do you want to give alignment to text? Then use inside Text widget this property:  ```textAlign: TextAlign.center```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey did you try textAlign property of Text widget like this -  `textAlign: TextAlign.center`

```
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 25, 25, 25),
  body: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        const Text("Güvenli ve Gizli", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.02),
        AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: ezAnimation,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return Center(
              child: Image.asset("assets/SecureAndHiddenIcon.png", fit: BoxFit.cover, color: Colors.white, height: 200)
            );
          }
        ),
        SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.02),
        Center(child: Text("Kullanıcıya değer vermek, güvenlik ve gizliliği sağlamaktan başlar. Malum tarayıcılar gibi bilgilerinizi satmayız!",textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white))), // !!!!!!!!!!!!! <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Hello. I saw that feature was removed in `Flutter 3.1.0` update. So I can't use that feature.

Comment: let me find alternate of this

Comment: The `TextAlign` feature didn't work when I tried it. After inserting the code you edited it worked. I'm very confused. Thanks for help.

Comment: @EmirBolat did you try Align widget?

Comment: Yes I tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: I am not able to find any info that textAlign is removed from 3.0

Comment: Even i am able to see textAlign on official document - [Text](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html)

Answer (score 1):

Please try using Alignment widget

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).